# WWW::Mechanize::Chrome How to close a tab

Tags: perl, google-chrome

I can't seem to figure out how to close a tab when using WWW::Mechanize::Chrome.

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Chrome->new();
$mech->get('https://www.google.com/');
```

There is no `$mech->close_tab()` method.

So the question is, how do you close the tab you're currently working with?

As [suggested by @zdim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52436012/1331451):

```
my $driver = $mech->driver
```

Seems to return the Chrome::DevToolsProtocol instance.

Then in order to close the tab, you have to call the close_tab() function and pass the current tab as the argument:

```
$mech->driver->close_tab($mech->tab);
```

This approach is generating the following error but it does close the tab:

```
Calling ->catch in void context at C:/Perl64/site/lib/Chrome/DevToolsProtocol.pm line 567
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `close_tab` method in [Chrome::DevToolsProtocol](https://metacpan.org/pod/Chrome::DevToolsProtocol), which is an

> asynchronous dispatcher for the DevTools protocol

and does not offer a method to instantiate an object.

The [WWW::Mechanize::Chrome](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Chrome) has the method [driver](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Chrome#$mech-%3Edriver) documented as

> Access the Chrome::DevToolsProtocol instance connecting to Chrome.

In a lucky case that this is simple perhaps `$chrome->driver->close_tab` may do it.

There is also an option `driver` for its constructor, described as

> A premade Chrome::DevToolsProtocol object.

with no further details. *Update: using this requires more work*.

I cannot yet pursue these clues since the install stubbornly fails at the end, after 54 (fifty-four) distributions are installed.

Hopefully this helps someone to figure it out though.

---

**Update**   After forcing the install I can confirm the question update

```
use warnings;
use strict;
...

my $chrome = WWW::Mechanize::Chrome->new(tab => undef);  # new tab for demo

$chrome->get('https://www.google.com/');

sleep 5;  
$chrome->driver->close_tab($chrome->tab); 
sleep 5;
```

This does issue a warning

```
Calling ->catch in void context at .../Chrome/DevToolsProtocol.pm line 567.
```

which, judged by the code quoted in the message, seems to be exposing a bug.

Comment: I have tried that but I'm getting an error: 'Can't call method "close_tab" on unblessed reference'.

$chrome->tab returns a hash with info on the current tab. It doesn't seem to be a Chrome::DevToolsProtocol object that you can use to call "close_tab"

Comment: @user735247 Alright, can you please then try to call `close_tab` directly on `$chrome`? This has installed 54 (fifty-four) distributions and then failed at "Building and testing ...". I'm trying again but can't yet play with it (forgot things since I last time tried this).

Comment: $chrome doesn't have a close_tab function:
Can't locate object method "close_tab" via package "WWW::Mechanize::Chrome"

Comment: @user735247 Updated my post to where I am with it now. If the install works out somehow I'll look more and update.

Comment: I updated my question to include the approach you suggested

Comment: @user735247 Got to install it and confirmed your update, and updated my answer. I will look more into it as I'm having trouble believing that one needs a protocol to close a tab

Answer (score 0):

There is no `->close_tab` method because I didn't find a need for it yet.

The "driver" object is a Chrome::DevToolsProtocol object, which is used to talk more directly to Chrome. Blindly  calling random methods on random results of methods is recommended here in the comments but is not a method that seems to be fruitful.

If you're hell-bent on closing a tab instead of letting the `$mech` object go out of scope, you can call

```
$mech->driver->close_tab( $mech->tab )->get();
```

but this will break further stuff you might have done with `$mech`. `->close_tab` returns a Future, so you shouldn't discard it blindly.

If you just want no tab to appear, have you considered the `headless` mode?

This question was cross-posted at https://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1222776 .

Comment: Thank you for pitching in and thank you for the modules. As for "_Blindly calling random methods on random results of methods_" (I take it to refer to my comments under my post) -- (1) I had to go at it "blind" since the docs are tight-lipped (2) It wasn't random, again as far as docs guided me. // As for tabs, are you saying that there is no good method to close a tab? I can't help it but note that the tests, which I watched a lot during failed installs (after 54 dependencies had been successfully installed), often open and close tabs.

Comment: Again, thank you for offering your work to all.  But I have to take another issue with your post here, with "_->close_tab returns a Future_" -- no, it doesn't; documentation says nothing of it.  I can read the code but since the docs only say "_Closes the tab_" it makes one think that the method, um, closes a tab.

Comment: The object is not really intended for external use. I've added some more documentation to it, but it still doesn't make much sense to use the module outside of WWW::Mechanize::Chrome. The tests should run Chrome in `headless` mode, that is, they shouldn't pop up (and subsequently close) tabs, but if you already have a Chrome instance running with the debug protocol launched, it might run headfull.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification; it did seem a stretch, even awkward to use it for that. There were no Chrome instances running (I use firefox). and the test starts Chrome. Then, it perhaps leaves it (I don't remember) in which case there would indeed be an instance for the next tests.

Comment: The tab stays open, even after $mech goes out of scope, unless it's closed using the driver's close_tab function.
Using "undef $mech" does not close the open tab either. At least on my end.